# How can I activate json compression for litespeed web server?

Tags: compression, litespeed, gtmetrix

I'm using lottiefiles and want to activate json compression to improve my gtmetrix score... How can I activate that with litespeed web server?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from Lucas Rolff at wpcache slack channel:

LiteSpeed does not automatically compress json, neither as gzip or brotli, the default compressed types are:

```
text/*, application/x-javascript, application/xml, application/javascript, image/svg+xml,application/rss+xml
```

This can be modified in the LiteSpeed WebAdmin console under Configuration -> Server -> Tuning, if you want to include json (MIME type being `application/json`), or use the AddOutputFilterByType as in the link above in your htaccess file.

---

I added `application/json` in my LiteSpeed WebAdmin console and it is working perfect!

Answer (score 0):

We have updated the default compressible type, MIME type `application/json` is in the default list now for new installation.